# Is there a name for polyhedra with uniform edge length?

Tags: geometry, 3d, polyhedra, solid-geometry

This seems like a very natural category of polyhedron to have, and would encompass a lot of things like the Platonic and Archimedean solids and more, but I haven't been able to find a name for it anywhere.

Comment: At http://www.numericana.com/answer/polyhedra.htm#equi they are called *equilateral* polyhedra. See also http://www.tum.dds.nl/polyh/heptagons/index.html where that term is used.

Answer (score 2):

There is a term called **isotoxal**, meaning that there exists a symmetry, which acts on all edges transitvely, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotoxal_figure.

The prefix **iso-** always unites into a single equivalence class. If you just wan to tell that those are alike (here: by size), then you could use the prefix **equi-** instead.

--- rk

Comment: Symmetry is another story. With some effort, we may produce a polyhedron with edges of same length, but without any symmetry at all.

Comment: Yes, this is why I added equitoxal instead of the more restrictive isotoxal too.

Comment: If you'd like other further restrictions, like overall convexity plus regularity of the polygonal faces, then in 3D you would just encompass the well-known set of Johnson solids, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_solid. Within 4D this same restriction would result in what is understood by the acronym CRF (convex regular faced polychora), e.g. cf. https://bendwavy.org/klitzing/explain/johnson.htm#crf.

Comment: *equilateral* would be equally (sic) acceptable.